# Problem with RHEL 5.5 compilation on Windows Host (Docker)

Tags: c++, docker, qt, compilation

I have a 64 bit Windows host machine, I have installed WSL (Debian), then docker, and then I'm trying to compile a Qt project on a Red Hat Linux 5.5 32 bit container(sharing a host directory with the code), but... doing the QMake...

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.3/bin/qmake MYFILE.pro -spec linux-g++ -r CONFIG+=debug
```

I get:

> QFSFileEngine::currentPath: stat(".") failed

And I can't continue my build. (The same qmake command works on a rhel5.5 virtual machine, it´s a container problem)

I launch the docker like this:

```
docker run -it -v E:\codeRepo:/root/codeRepo rhl55 sh /root/codeRepo/00-scripts/make/makeScript.sh
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile? It might help with troubleshooting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

It's a filesystem problem. I moved "E:\codeRepo" to "\\wsl$\Debian\codeRepo" (WSL filesystem as a network drive in windows) and it works.

Now i'm sharing with the docker an ext4 folder and there is no problem with QMake.

So, this doesn't works:

```
docker run -it -v E:\codeRepo:/root/codeRepo rhl55 sh /root/codeRepo/00-scripts/make/makeScript.sh
```

But this works:

```
docker run -it -v \\wsl$\Debian\codeRepo:/root/codeRepo rhl55 sh /root/codeRepo/00-scripts/make/makeScript.sh
```